# What is this overlay and how do I turn it off?

Tags: windows-10, overlay

[image]

This overlay pops up after I take a snip of the current page sometimes, and always pops up during gaming. I can't pinpoint what app is causing this, and even after turning off both NVidia GeForce Experience and the AMD Radeon Software by both tray icon and task manager force stopping, it doesn't go away. I plan to use this computer during class later so I do not need this overlay. The only tried-and-true way of getting rid of it is to restart the computer.

It appears that the GPU data is for the AMD Radeon Vega 8 (integrated GPU) instead of the discreet GeForce GTX 1650.

OS: Windows 10 Home 64 bit
Model: Victus by HP 16
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
GPU: AMD Radeon Vega 8/GeForce GTX 1650

Comment: What snip app are you using? Have you gone through your running system apps? Start up entries?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + O

It's the AMD Radeon Performance Overlay. Can be disabled in the AMD Software: Settings > Hotkeys menu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).